# Single tag constructors in Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have a data type like this:

```
data A = A T.Text deriving (Generic, Show)

instance A.ToJSON A
```

If I use `A.encode` to it:

```
A.encode $ A "foobar" -- "foobar"
```

Then I use `singleTagConstructors` on it:

```
instance A.ToJSON A where
  toEncoding a = A.genericToEncoding $ A.defaultOptions { A.tagSingleConstructors = True }

A.encode $ A "foobarquux" -- "{tag: A, contents: foobarquux}"
```

At some point I made another data type:

```
newtype Wrapper a = Wrapper 
  { unWrap :: a
  } deriving (Show)

instance A.ToJSON a => A.ToJSON (Wrapper a) where 
  toJSON w = A.object [ "wrapped" A..= unWrap w ]
```

Here's the part where I get confused:

```
A.encode $ Wrapper $ A "foobar" -- "{wrapped: foobar}"
```

How do I get the result to be like this?

```
"{wrapped: {tag: A, contents: foobarquux}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you can always implement the `Wrapper` instance with `tagSingleConstructors = False`, like this:

```
instance Generic a => A.ToJSON (Wrapper a) where 
  toJSON w = A.object [ "wrapped" A..= encA (unWrap w) ]
    where
      encA = A.genericToEncoding $ A.defaultOptions { A.tagSingleConstructors = False }
```

---

But I don't see why you'd want to do that.

If you control the API, then you don't need the `tag` field: the expected type of the wrapped value is already statically known, so `tag` would not be helpful.

And if you don't control the API, I would recommend representing it very explicitly, for example as a record that exactly matches the API shape. Otherwise you run a risk of accidentally breaking the API by making unrelated changes in remote parts of the codebase.

Comment: I was making an http api and sending back error response constructed from sum types encoded as json with `tag`. It was nice that I could see what was returned because of the `tag`. So to be consistent I decided to make  a non-sum types to be tagged too. But thinking about it maybe I'm exposing too much of its internal by doing that.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is how you implemented your custom `ToJSON` instance.

```hs
instance A.ToJSON A where
  toEncoding a = A.genericToEncoding $ A.defaultOptions { A.tagSingleConstructors = True }
```

Since you do not implement `toJSON` directly default implementation from typeclass definition is used.

```hs
class ToJSON a where -- excerpt from Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON
    -- | Convert a Haskell value to a JSON-friendly intermediate type.
    toJSON     :: a -> Value

    default toJSON :: (Generic a, GToJSON' Value Zero (Rep a)) => a -> Value
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

Effectively, you have the following instance:

```hs
instance A.ToJSON A where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
  toEncoding a = A.genericToEncoding $ A.defaultOptions { A.tagSingleConstructors = True }
```

While `toEncoding` uses expected tagged encoding, `toJSON` uses default encoding (which does not tag single constructors). This inconsistency is the root cause of the confusion. Later, in wrapper's `ToJSON` instance `.=` operator used. Internally, it uses `toJSON` and not `toEncoding`:

```hs
class KeyValue kv where
    (.=) :: ToJSON v => Text -> v -> kv
    infixr 8 .=

instance KeyValue Pair where
    name .= value = (name, toJSON value)
```

As a solution, you should either define only `toJSON` and keep default `toEncoding` implementation (that uses `toJSON`) or implement both.